# cleaning framework/sessions folder after every request

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

As I found my **framework/sessions** folder becoming ***bulkier***. Because **laravel** creating ***session*** files on **every request**. I am using laravel 5.1 . I don't want sessions on all requests. or I want to delete framework/sessions files automatically after each request is completed. I tried session->flash. But files are still there.

I tried **$request->session()->flush()**; But it is not removing file from framework/sessins directory

I want to avoid this for only curl requests. As, I got some webhooks from eCommerce open sources and it (laravel) creating multiple sessions on mulptiple webhooks.

```
a:3:{s:6:"_token";s:40:"AXqkhlwBwbJGcfG3l8ZVzN991HQnYwfioQUd38Mz";s:9:"_sf2_meta";a:3:{s:1:"u";i:1487576780;s:1:"c";i:1487576780;s:1:"l";s:1:"0";}s:5:"flash";a:2:{s:3:"old";a:0:{}s:3:"new";a:0:{}}}
```

Comment: You have tried session->flush() or session->flash() ?

Comment: Yes I tried $request->session()->flush(); But it is not removing file from framework/sessins directory.
Muthu Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use session anywhere in application then set session driver to array.

Edit `config/sessions.php` set

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'array')
```

or locally using `.env`

```
SESSION_DRIVER=array
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Yes, I can except some routes by using middleware by assigning SESSION_DRIVER=array

Answer (score 0):

sorry ,can't using comment, just using other driver like redis/memcached. so it won't get bulkier.. 
the only way to delete it is to call $request->session()->flush();

Comment: I don't want to change session driver type. Anyways thanks for your help.